# Regex capture word follow by a number as a group

Tags: regex, ruby

I need to match this string:

```
Cattle: Sheep: Pigs: 
Meat –0 days Meat – 0 days Meat – 0 days
Milk – 0 hours Milk – 0 hours
```

To create the following capture groups:

```
[cattle:, sheep:, pigs:]
[meat - 0 days, meat - 0 days, meat - 0 days]
[milk - 0 days, milk - 0 days]
```

---

I've tried to have a go myself but I am getting nowhere, I currently have something like this but it matches digits and spaces all over the string

```
(?!Cattle|Sheep|Pigs)(\b[Meat\s-\s\d*]\b)
```

I am capturing the cattle, speed and pigs strings in a different regex, hence the neg lookahead.

EDIT: Sorry I should have specific more. These are all on a separate line split into an array.

Comment: What is the output you want here, and also are you using a programming language with your regex package?

Comment: Ruby. Using `string.scan`. I basically need a capture group for each line. So one for each species, then one that holds the food type, length of time and the unit of time. The order matters as index 0 of the species would match index 0 of meat and milk. That make sense? Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: Any reason that you are not splitting the string on newlines, looping, and using conditions to test which type of line entry you are looking at?

Comment: Do you mean getting consecutive groups? `(?:(Cattle): (Sheep): (Pigs):.*\r?\n|\G)(\S+ *–\d+ \S+) (\S+ *– \d+ \S+) (\S+ *– \d+ \S+)\r?\n|((?<=\G).+)` [Rubular demo](https://rubular.com/r/csd2raX1TRHCdb) Or to see the highlighted groups https://regex101.com/r/kW8yPz/1

Comment: @MonkeyZeus the string is already split on new lines, basically at each iteration I want to capture the groups that are there so I can take them and organize them in a readable manner. That's why I thought a capture group for each type and since they are ordered, index 0 on each line would have the matching data.

Comment: So `IF line starts with cattle then do x ELSEIF line starts with Meat then do y ELSEIF line starts with Milk then do z` is not plausible?

Comment: Nope. I have 3,000 documents to parse. This particular regex is only one of the edge cases, not to mention all the typos, random spaces, periods etc. Basically whoever is in charge of maintaining them...is useless.

Comment: You should consider showing a more diverse set of data which is representative of your situation and explain how you plan to use it because a pure regex solution could be difficult...

Comment: Yeah, it's proving a pain in the ass but @Cary Swoveland has provided a solution that does exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str =<<END
Cattle: Sheep: Pigs: 
Meat –0 days Meat – 0 days Meat – 0 days
Milk – 0 hours Milk – 0 hours
END
```

```
str.each_line.map { |line| line.chomp.downcase.split(/(?<=:|days|hours) */) }
  #=> [["cattle:", "sheep:", "pigs:"],
  #    ["meat –0 days", "meat – 0 days", "meat – 0 days"],
  #    ["milk – 0 hours", "milk – 0 hours"]]
```

The regular expression reads, "match one or more spaces that are immediately preceded by a colon, the word 'days' or the word 'hours', `(?<=:|days|hours)` being a positive *lookbehind*.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: There may be an issue with the value of `–` it's not what it appears to be if you cut and paste from the OP's example. Paste this in irb `'–' == '-'`

Comment: @lacostenycoder Yep, it's not the same as `-`. It caught me off guard. Unfortunately there are instances of both of them existing.

Comment: @CarySwoveland This is exactly what I am looking for, this will allow me to simple build a proper object out of the data. Thank you.

Comment: @Gibbo can you chime in on the problems with `-` ? if you meant to have two diff characters for them in your example or not. That problem caused us lots of hair pulling trying to make a regex based off of subtly different ascii characters.

Comment: @lacostenycoder, a wise man from the east once said, "hair-pulling builds character".

Comment: @lacostenycoder I didn't make that example up, I have pulled it right from a parsed docx file. It is full of stuff like that. Only way around it so far is to log everything and look where data is missing. It's not bad since I have the file name attached to the log output, so if I see it skipping over an entire section, I can investigate to make sure that there are no weird ascii characters.

EDIT: It's been nearly 2 weeks at this. I'm dead inside.

Comment: @Gibbo, consider cleaning up the string as follows: `str.gsub(/(?<= ). ?(?=\d+ +(?:days|hours))/, '- ') #=> "Cattle: Sheep: Pigs: \nMeat - 0 days Meat - 0 days Meat - 0 days\nMilk - 0 hours Milk - 0 hours\n"`. This regex (which I expect you'd have to modify) matches any character (a hyphen, emdash, etc.) optionally followed by a space, the match being immediately preceded by a space (*positive lookbehind*) and immediately followed by one or more digits followed by one or more spaces folllowed by `"days"` or `"hours"` (*positive lookahead*).